If A is closed then $X/A$ is a hausdorff space
I m trying to proof the following statement:
Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$ a subset. We write $X/A$ as de quotient space of $X/\sim$ wherein $\forall x,y \in X: x \sim y \iff (x =y $ or $ x,y \in A)$. Let now the topology of $X/A$ be the quotient topology induced by $p: X \to X/A$. Assume now that  X is compact and a Hausdorff space. Proof that if $A$ is closed, that then $X/A$ is a Hausdorff space too.
Now what is confusing to me is, I saw in other similar questions here, that a pre-requirement for this to work, is that $X$ must be regular for it to work. I wonder now, if I missed some detail here in this exercise or if the exercise is wrong?
As for the proof, this here is what I ve got so far:
Proof:
Choose now $xA, yA \in X/A $ arbitrarily with $xA \neq yA$ and thus is evidently $x \neq y$. Now we have $p^{-1}(xA)=x$ and $p^{-1}(yA)=y$. Because we assumed that $X$ was a Hausdorff space, there must be open neighborhoods $U_x, U_y$ around $x$ and $y$ resp. in $X$ such as  $U_x \cap U_y = \emptyset$. Now is $p(U_x) = \{zA | z \in U_x\}$ en $p(U_y) = \{zA | z \in U_y\}$. Further are $U_x = p^{-1}(\{zA | z \in U_x\})$ and $U_y = p^{-1}(\{zA | z \in U_y\})$ open in $X$ and because $p$ is a quotient map, we know that $\{zA | z \in U_x\}$ and $\{zA | z \in U_y\}$ is open in $X/A$. We further know that $xA \in \{zA | z \in U_x\}$ and $yA \in \{zA | z \in U_y\}$ and on top of this is  $\{zA | z \in U_x\} \cap \{zA | z \in U_x\} = \{ zA | z \in U_x \cap U_y\} = \emptyset$. What ultimately proofs that $X/A$ is a Hausdorff space.        $\blacksquare$
Does this make even in the slightest any sense? I would really appreciate if anyone could help me further with this. Thank you in advance.

Remember (or find a proof in your book, there’s a proof in Munkres, for instance) that compact Hausdorff implies regular :)

For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplication.

You certainly should need disjoint neighborhoods of the entire equivalence classes of $x$ and $y$. There are several errors I spot immediately in your proof. Certainly $p^{-1}(xA)=x$ is wrong and you also write $U_x = p^{-1}({zA|z\in U_x})$. You seem to have the wrong picture entirely in your mind, unless I misunderstand you completely.

Ted Shifrin, Yes indeed, for some reason I had a topological group and cosets in mind and was a bit confused, which the exercise I was  before working on was about. Malady Thank you for your input, now I can see the link between my question and the similar question proposed by  Qiaochu Yuan. Thank you

Yes, your notation is the algebraic notation, but the statements are still incorrect.
